# Find DataRecord from DataItem for Infragistics DataPresenter

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

I'm trying to retrieve the `DataRecord` associated with a given data item bound to my `XamDataGrid`. Is there any way to find the `DataRecord` other than enumerating through all the `DataRecords` in the collection and comparing the `DataRecord.DataItem` to the dataItem in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GetDataRecordFromDataItem method exposed by the DataRecordCollection and this could be used to get a DataRecord from the DataItem

http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WPF/2011.2/CLR4.0/?page=InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataRecordCollection~GetDataRecordFromDataItem.html